# .Net FTP Library

Tags: c#

I've used FileZilla as my favourite FTP application for quite a while, and admire its amazing functionality.

As I'm a programmer myself, I often run into situation where I need FTP support. And then I always find myself wanting to use FileZilla as a base FTP component in my system, because it supports just about everything I need.

My problem is that I program in C#.NET, and thus can't use the FileZilla source code directly, even though it's open source. Even if it was possible to use it directly, I wouldn't know where to start when looking at the source code, since I can't even get it to compile in VS.NET (I try to compile it as C++, of course).

Would it be possible to wrap the FileZilla code in C# using P/Invoke so we would get the best free .NET FTP library in existance?

Answer (score 13):

While you could wrap just about anything, controlling the interface and error conditions is going to be very challenging. I'd recommend you check for a component/library

This class is already in the .NET Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

This open source apparently supports SFTP: http://sshnet.codeplex.com/

Or there are a few commercials ones: http://www.dart.com/ptftpnet.aspx or http://www.rebex.net/ftp.net/

or a search of stackoverflow reveals lots of .net/FTP related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+FTP+library

Comment: @Mubin Please see http://cheated.by.safabyte.net/ which shows Component Pro Ultimate FTP likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen Rebex software. TY

Comment: @iokevins Deleted my comment. Wasn't aware of that. Thanks!!